# COUNT( ) on multiple columns each having a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, android-sqlite

**`EDITED :`**

I have a Table **`Attendance`**.

[image]

Where **`0`** stands for false, and **`1`** stands for true.

I need to get the **`count or sum`** of **`Present`** , **`Absent`** & **`Leaves`** When

- `Present = 1`
- `Absent = 1`
- `Leave = 1`

The result what i need is like :

```
 Present 3
 Absent 2
 Leave 1
```

Can any one guide me what the query will be. I have tried with **`COUNT()`** on single coulmn but dnt know how to do this on multiple columns.

Comment: Can you expand your model here? For example: are the 3 columns number of days, or true/false? If True/False, is there an entry for each Name value for each day?

Comment: You should edit your question to provide the results that you want and SQL code that you have already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so,using expression in sum will result as a boolean and you can have your count on basis of your conditions

```
select 
name,
sum(Present = 1) Presentcount,
sum(Absent = 1) Absentcount,
sum(Leaves= 1) Leavescount
from Attendance
group by name
```

Comment: Thnx Alot @M Khalid Junaid Bro. That is what exactly I want.

Answer (score 1):

If the items can have values of only `0` or `1`, you can simply sum them up.

```
SELECT
    SUM(Present) as PresentCnt
,   SUM(Absent) as AbsentCnt
,   ...
FROM ...
```

If other values are allowed, use `SUM` using a `CASE` expression as an argument:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN Present=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Present_One
,   SUM(CASE WHEN Absent=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Absent_One
,   ...
FROM ...
```

Comment: Thnx @dasblinkenlight, Thats a fine one.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(present),sum(absent),sum(leave) from Attendance
```

[assuming they are 0s and 1s]